# AWS Lambda, AWS API Gateway, AWS Cloudfront gives 403 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, godaddy, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lambda, amazon-api-gateway

I run a Django project deployed on AWS lambda using serverless Zappa framework. This can be accessed by a randomly generated link from AWS API Gateway lets say:-

> randomly-generated-link.aws.amazon.com/production

I have also created an SSL certificate from ACM and verified it with my domain lets say

> example.com

Now when i run zappa certify, this command certifies my domain successfully and creates a custom domain under API gateway console with the following configurations:-

> Endpoint Configuration Edge optimized
>
> **Target Domain Name** d25ihv8a5022zi.cloudfront.net
>
> **Hosted Zone ID** A2FDTNGATAQYW6
>
> **ACM Certificate** example.com (c504428e)

Now, I need to point my domain name `example.com` to `randomly-generated-link.aws.amazon.com/production`, so I updated my records on Godaddy with CNAME as follows:-

> TYPE - CNAME NAME - example.com VALUE - d25ihv8a5022zi.cloudfront.net
>   TTL - 1 HOUR

EXPECTED RESULT - My application thats running on `randomly-generated-link.aws.amazon.com` show be accessable from `example.com`.

WHAT I GET - 403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied. Bad request. 
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)

Comment: Are you using `https://...` when accessing the API you created? API Gateway does not support unencrypted HTTP and on an Edge Optimized deplohment, you'll get an error from CloudFront if you try without.

Comment: I am able to access my application on https://randomly-generated-link.aws.amazon.com/production but the error comes when I visit example.com

Comment: @abi-crazieeee Did you fix the issue?

Comment: @Krishna Mohan Yes, Create a hosted zone on your AWS Route53 for your domain. Set route53_enabled to True in your zappa_settings.json and then recertify. It may take upto 40 minutes for the dns to propagate.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the **Alternate Domain Name** for the CloudFront distribution to `example.com`?

---

[image: Alternate Domain Name]

---

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This is a built-in "hidden" CloudFront distribution associated with an API Gateway Edge Optimized deployment.  They aren't visible in the AWS console, and are auto-configured.

Comment: That's right, I don't see a CloudFront distribution on AWS console.

Comment: As usual, it's in the docs but I didn't find it until I read your answer.  Thanks :-)